# Under what circumstances is the wedge sum of two spaces "the" wedge sum of two spaces?

Tags: general-topology

Often, one sees people refer to "the" wedge sum of two topological spaces. However, the wedge sum involves a choice of two different points, one from each of these spaces. Sometimes, e.g., if both of the spaces are $S^1$, the choice of points is irrelevant, and you always end up with the same space. Other times, e.g., if both of the spaces are $[0, 1]$, the choice of points does matter, as choosing a point in the interior from either will not result in a manifold, while choosing both points to be on the boundary will. So, my question is, under what circumstances is the choice of base point immaterial?

Comment: What do you mean by "same"? Typically you'd never get a unique wedge sum upto homemorphism, like you said, but the two spaces you have are homotopy equivalent. However there are exotic examples where the wedge sum is not independent on the choice of points even upto homotopy equivalence.

Comment: I did mean homeomorphic, but since you mentioned it, the question of being homotopy equivalent is also interesting.

Comment: Better terminology would be "the wedge sum of two pointed spaces." This is well defined, independent of any choices. Talking about "the wedge sum of two spaces" is convenient but sloppy, just like talking about "the fundamental group of a space."

Comment: Professor Lee points out the issue very precisely: after all, wedging is a construction of based topological spaces (the relevant category being $\mathbf{Top}_*$). If, however, the relevant topological spaces are "homogeneous", that is, $(X, p)$ and $(X, q)$ are based homotopy equivalent for any pair of points $p, q$ in $X$, then the wedge sum is independent of the choice of base-points.